# Silently re-using data vs requiring the user to pass a "re-use" argument?

Tags: design-patterns, coding-style, ui

### Context

After creating a (bash) CLI interface that creates self-signed SSL certificates (for onion domains), the user can choose to re-use some of the data that is created in past runs. For example, a self-signed root-ca may be used for multiple services, which may be created in separate runs. Another example are onion domains, which may be re-used for a specific service (if for example the port on which the service runs is updated, without updating the onion domain).

The idea is that the user passes a list of services and accompanying ports as CLI arg. Next, the onion domains and self-signed SSL certificates are made automatically for those services.

### Doubt

I intend to write a prerequisites check that checks whether those pieces of data already exist or not. If the data does exist, the user can:

- delete that piece of data and create a new one (e.g. a new SSL certificate for that service).
- re-use the old piece of data.
  If the data does not yet exist, the code will:
- create a new piece of that data.

### Pattern I

The CLI user interface may be as simple as possible if the code automatically detects whether or not the relevant pieces of data already exist or not, and if yes, just automatically re-use that piece of data.

### Pattern II

The approach of pattern I is in contrast with doing things with complete control. So another approach would be to throw an error if such a piece of data already exists, in case the user did not pass a `-re-use` nor `overwrite` command.

### Question

Is there a guide/design pattern that can be used to determine which of those latter 2 strategies would be better?

Comment: Can you clarify "onion domains"? I haven't heard that term before. I assume you mean **sub domains**?

Comment: For onion domains in particular, they are supposed to be anonymous, and if you reuse data this allows everyone to know that two onion domains are run by the same person.

Comment: @GregBurghardt "onion domains" are (usually) web servers in the Tor network, which end in .onion

Comment: @user253751 Thank you for providing the clarification, my apologies for not making that clear at the start. Thank you for the heads-up on the dangers of re-using data related to onion domains, it is noted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately, both approaches can be valid. What is important is that you communicate clearly to the user what is happening.

Your Pattern 1 is outcome-oriented. If there is nothing to do, nothing will be done. If parts are already done, they will be reused. For example, this is how Makefiles generally work. This is a good approach if output artefacts are expensive to create, if there are intermediate steps that can be reused, and if you might need to resume an interrupted process. However, it requires a way to tell whether those intermediate artefacts are still up to date. Makefiles compare the timestamps of files for this, so that any output artefact must be younger than its input data. A more sophisticated alternative is to use a hash function to create a fingerprint for the current configuration, and to use this fingerprint in the names of intermediate files. There is typically a way to `clean` all generated files, so that the entire process can be run from scratch.

Your Pattern 2 is action-oriented. You expect the script to always do something, and the user tells it what to do. There might be safety features to prevent unexpected overwriting of old data, especially for high-value data like private keys. This gives the user more control and more safety during manual operation, but it can be more difficult for scripting, e.g. if a script is tested in a clean environment where the action is performed successfully, but is then actually used in an environment where old output files already exist, causing an unexpected error.

In either case, it makes sense to make the scripts configurable so that they can work on unrelated states/directories/projects/contexts. It might be OK to default to creating/checking files in the current working directory, but scripting is made easier if you explicitly provide a name or path for the context. This also simplifies testing and debugging.

I want to reiterate [user253751's comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/445288/silently-re-using-data-vs-requiring-the-user-to-pass-a-re-use-argument#comment979492_445288) that reusing any information across your configuration of .onion services makes it possible to connect them, potentially jeopardizing your anonymity.